# PLSQL - "SP2-0552: bind variable not declared", but seems not a colon issue

Tags: oracle, plsql

I try this plsql script from SQL Developer, and it returns
SP2-0552: bind variable "MAN_ID" not declared

(I changed values and some names, so I hope there are no typo)

```
DECLARE
  TYPE FUNCTIONALITIES IS VARRAY(12) of VARCHAR2(10);
  FUNCS  FUNCTIONALITIES := FUNCTIONALITIES('Func1', 'Func2', 'Func3', 'Func4', 'Func5', 'Func6', 'Func7', 'Func8', 'Func9', 'Func10', 'Func11', 'Func12');
  MAN_ID  NUMBER(12);
  SW_PRO_ID  NUMBER(12);
  REL  VARCHAR2(10) := 'Release';
  EXT_B  VARCHAR2(10) := 'ExtensionB';

BEGIN

  select ID into MAN_ID from MANUFACTURERS where MANUFACTURER = 'EE';
  select ID into SW_PRO_ID from SW_PROFILE where MANUFACTURER_ID = :MAN_ID and RELEASE = :REL and EXTENSIONB = :EXT_B;

  FOR i IN 1..FUNC.COUNT LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
      'INSERT INTO SW_PROFILE_FEATURE (ID, SW_PROFILE_ID, FEATURE, CREATION_DATE)
          SELECT SQ_SW_PROFILE_FEATURE_ID.NEXTVAL, '''|| SW_PRO_ID ||''', '''|| FUNCS(i) ||''', SYSDATE FROM DUAL
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM RMM.SW_PROFILE_FEATURE WHERE SW_PROFILE_ID = '''|| SW_PRO_ID ||''' AND FEATURE = '''|| FUNCS(i) ||''')';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
      'UPDATE SW_PROFILE_FEATURE SET SW_PROFILE_ID = '''|| SW_PRO_ID ||''', FEATURE = '''|| FUNCS(i) ||''', CREATION_DATE = SYSDATE
        WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT ROWID FROM SW_PROFILE_FEATURE WHERE SW_PROFILE_ID = '''|| SW_PRO_ID ||''' AND FEATURE = '''|| FUNCS(i) ||''')';

  END LOOP;

  COMMIT COMMENT 'Inserted new SW_PROFILE_FEATURE records';

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  IF SQLCODE != -1 THEN RAISE; END IF;
END;
/
```

I have to do a series of 12 inserts, which differ by the value of FEATURE field which cointains functionalities names.
For some reasons, some of them could already be into the table, so in that case I have to update them, to be sure they'll be as expected at the end.

So I thought to put all 12 functionalities into a varray and then loop them with an "insert where not exists" and an "update where" matching primary keys.

I tried to look for similar issues over the internet, but most of people's issue was just putting a colon before the variable into the "select into" statement.
That seems not my case.

(If you find also other issues with the script, please tell me)

Comment: Remove the colons from `= :MAN_ID and RELEASE = :REL and EXTENSIONB = :EXT_B`? Those are bind variables, and presumably not declared, when you appear to want to refer to the local PL/SQL variables with those names? Also - why are you using dynamic SQL?

Comment: I really din't think anymore to those colons... will it recognize as variables without?
Tomorrow I'll try, servers are shut down at the moment.

Comment: Yes, `REL` (without the colon) will refer to the PL/SQL variable with that name (as long as the table doesn't have a column with that name, which it doesn't appear to; prefixes are often used for variable names to avoid possible confusion/clashes).

Comment: Also note that if you still need to use dynamic SQL for whatever reason, don't use concatenation to pass data to statements: use bind variables instead and `execute immediate ... using bind1, ..., bindN`

Answer (score 0):

`:MAN_ID` would be an externally defined bind variable. `MAN_ID` is a locally defined PL/SQL variable.

If you want to use the local variable then do not prefix it with `:`.

However, for `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statements you **should** wherever possible use bind variables and then provide them with a `USING` clause to pass the values from the PL/SQL scope to the SQL scope of the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement (and prevent SQL injection vulnerabilities):

```sql
DECLARE
  TYPE FUNCTIONALITIES IS VARRAY(12) of VARCHAR2(10);
  FUNCS  FUNCTIONALITIES := FUNCTIONALITIES('Func1', 'Func2', 'Func3', 'Func4', 'Func5', 'Func6', 'Func7', 'Func8', 'Func9', 'Func10', 'Func11', 'Func12');
  MAN_ID  NUMBER(12);
  SW_PRO_ID  NUMBER(12);
  REL  VARCHAR2(10) := 'Release';
  EXT_B  VARCHAR2(10) := 'ExtensionB';
BEGIN
  select ID
  into   MAN_ID
  from   MANUFACTURERS
  where  MANUFACTURER = 'EE';

  select ID
  into   SW_PRO_ID
  from   SW_PROFILE
  where  MANUFACTURER_ID = MAN_ID
  and    RELEASE         = REL
  and    EXTENSIONB      = EXT_B;

  FOR i IN 1..FUNC.COUNT LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
      'INSERT INTO SW_PROFILE_FEATURE (ID, SW_LVC_PROFILE_ID, FEATURE, CREATION_DATE)
          SELECT SQ_SW_PROFILE_FEATURE_ID.NEXTVAL, :SW_PRO_ID, :func, SYSDATE FROM DUAL
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM RMM.SW_PROFILE_FEATURE WHERE SW_PROFILE_ID = :SW_PRO_ID AND FEATURE = :func)'
      USING SW_PRO_ID, FUNCS(i), SW_PRO_ID, FUNCS(i);

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
      'UPDATE SW_PROFILE_FEATURE SET SW_LVC_PROFILE_ID = :SW_PRO_ID, FEATURE = :func, CREATION_DATE = SYSDATE
        WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT ROWID FROM SW_PROFILE_FEATURE WHERE SW_PROFILE_ID = :SW_PRO_ID AND FEATURE = :func)'
      USING SW_PRO_ID, FUNCS(i), SW_PRO_ID, FUNCS(i);

  END LOOP;

  COMMIT;
  -- Inserted new SW_PROFILE_FEATURE records;

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  IF SQLCODE != -1 THEN RAISE; END IF;
END;
/
```

You probably don't need to use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` and can do it all in a single `MERGE` statement:

```sql
MERGE INTO SW_PROFILE_FEATURE dst
USING (
  WITH functionalities (func) AS (
    SELECT 'Func1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Func2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Func3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Func4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Func5' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Func6' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Func7' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Func8' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Func9' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Func10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Func11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Func12' FROM DUAL
  )
  SELECT s.id,
         f.func
  FROM   manufacturers m
         INNER JOIN sw_profile s
         ON MANUFACTURER_ID = MAN_ID
         CROSS JOIN functionalities f
  WHERE  s.release      = 'Release'
  AND    s.extensionb   = 'ExtensionB'
  AND    m.manufacturer = 'EE'
) src
ON (dst.sw_profile_id = src.id AND dst.feature = src.func)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (ID, SW_LVC_PROFILE_ID, FEATURE, CREATION_DATE)
  VALUES (SQ_SW_PROFILE_FEATURE_ID.NEXTVAL, src.id, src.func, SYSDATE)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET SW_LVC_PROFILE_ID = src.id,
      CREATION_DATE     = SYSDATE;
```

Comment: I like the merge idea, thank you!

Comment: It returns an error:

Error SQL: ORA-38104: columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated "DST"."SW_LVC_PROFILE_ID"
38104. 00000 -  "Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated: %s"

But if I do insert then update, it works.

Comment: Over the internet I found this explanation:
"You cannot update a column which is used in the ON clause"

On that issue it suggest to move the field from the ON clause into a WHERE for the UPDATE, but that case only had WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE.
In my case I fear it wouldn't work fine for the WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT to not have that field into the ON clause.

Comment: I made a try with only the WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE and moving the field from ON clause to a WHERE... as expected, also the dst.FEATURE field has same issue, because I cannot update fields referred in the ON clause.

I'm thinking to give up the WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE part, at the end it would only update the CREATION_DATE.
So I'll use only up to the WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT section.

Comment: @Patcha You should not need to update the `FEATURE` column as you already check if it is set in the `ON` clause and you are just going to be updating it to the same value (updated the answer to remove it). If you do need to update the feature (but I don't see why you would) then you can `OUTER JOIN` the destination table in the `USING` clause and then merge `ON` the `ROWID` pseudo-column (something like [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/W-LXrswh) - however, I don't have your tables so cannot test it).

Comment: Yes, actually I think that using only UPDATE SET CREATION_DATE = SYSDATE would work. Because, as you said, the other two field would be updated with the same value already set. But as I said, I decided to give up the UPDATE and left the original CREATION_DATE in case of existing record. Thank you anyway, the tip will be useful in future in case I'll also need the UPDATE section for different queries on different tables.